# Tree generation in NetworkX

Tags: python, tree, graph-theory, networkx

NetworkX has a built in method for generating a tree:

> G = nx.balanced_tree(2,4)

but I need to build a random tree which will be created using just the total number of nodes. The height and children of each node should be more randomized.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: This question needs some clarification: what **exactly** is a random tree?  Consider 4 nodes, there are 2 general configurations: a star or a path.  Should you get each with equal probability?  If we look at labeling the nodes: there are 12 non-equivalent ways to label the path, but only 4 ways to label the star.  So should we get a path 3/4 of the time and the star 1/4?

Comment: I'm looking to build something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sjij.jpg. The children of each node should be a random number between 0-5

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want as the output.  I think you mean each node should have 0 to 5 children.  (so you're asking for a rooted tree?).    How is it determined how many children a node has (from what distribution?)

Comment: Yes the tree should have a starting node(Root) and then each node should have 0-5 children. The number doesn't depend on anything, I will just use a function randint(0,5) and that number will determine the number of nodes.

Comment: and how does the total number of nodes affect anything?